# .htaccess redirect http:/www.domain.com/songs.php?movie=journey to http:/www.domain.com/songs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please Help!

Need to redirect from http:/www.domain.com/songs.php?movie=journey to http:/www.domain.com/songs

I need to remove query strings(?movie=journey). I don't want them anymore.

I tried this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^movie=journey$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /songs/$1 [R,L]
```

But in browser it is showing like this http:/www.domain.com/songs/songs.php?movie=journey

Answer (score 0):

Add `?` at the end of last rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^movie=journey$
RewriteRule ^songs.php(.*)$ /songs/$1? [R,L]
```

Comment: http://www.domain.com/songs/songs.php

The url showing in browser this way.

But I don't want that songs.php in url. 

I want the url to be
http://www.domain.com/songs

Comment: Another problem again.
I got this with

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^movie=([a-zA-Z0-9% ]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /songs/? [R,L]

if it is like
songs.php?movie=Racha%20Title%20Song or
songs.php?movie=Racha Title Song

it is not redirecting

Can you tell me regular expression for this plz?